# Injective implies invertible? Injective and well-defined implies bijective?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, continuity, linear-transformations

I have two questions regarding functions regarding linear maps: (Let $X$ and $Y$ be to Banach spaces)

1. If $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective, then $T^{-1}$ exists, right?
2. If $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective and $T^{-1}$ well-defined, then $T$ is bijective, right?

Am I right in these questions? Or are there counter-examples?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Forgot to mention that $T$ is bounded (making $T^{-1}$ bounded as well, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $T$ is for instance the inclusion of a proper subspace then $T$ is injective but not surjective. The inverse $T^{-1}$ cannot be well-defined unless $T$ is also surjective.

In other words, $T^{-1}$ is well-defined if and only if $T$ is injective and surjective. By the way, if $T$ is bounded then $T^{-1}$ is automatically bounded as well by the [bounded inverse theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, this answers a lot of questions.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If $T:X\to Y$ is injective, you can consider the application $T^*:X\to T(X)$. Then $T^*$ is bijective and has inverse..